# Rsync --checksum does not catch changed files

Tags: macos, ubuntu, rsync

I am transferring files from a Linux computer to a Mac. The connection sometimes drops and I restart. This is usually fine, but I check everything for a possible data corruption using md5sum.

With `rsync -avc` it took time to generate the checksums, but then it reported everything in order.

I have double checked this with `md5sum` and found they are different. Substantially different. It seems that either `rsync` checksum is too simple (crc?) or just not working.

Linux rsync is 3.1.1 and on OS X I have tried the native 2.6.9 and homebrew-installed 3.1.2.

Any ideas?

edit:

linux:
`md5sum filename`
os x:
`md5 filename`
and then see that the hashes are different which i verified by checking the contents of the files.

Comment: Please update you question with exact commands you used to compare source and destination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--checksum` on its own is not enough, and only worked when using rsyncd.

I figured out how to do delta transfers with rsync over ssh using these three parameters. works great now, fixing corrupt transfers.

`rsync -av --checksum --inplace --no-whole-file user@server:/source/ /destination/`